# What's wrong in my link-list code for C? `Add Two Numbers`

Tags: c, linked-list

Problem 2 on Leetcode:

Add Two Numbers.

My code here:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2){
  struct ListNode* result;  
  volatile bool carry = false;
  while ((l1 != NULL) || (l2 != NULL) ) {
    result = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode) );
    result->next = NULL;
    int v1 = 0;     
    if (l1 != NULL) {
      v1 = l1->val;
      l1 = l1->next;
    }
    
    int v2 = 0;     
    if (l2 != NULL) {
      v2 = l2->val;
      l2 = l2->next;
    }
        
    int sum = v1 + v2;
    if (carry == true)
      sum += 1;
    carry = (sum > 9);
        
    result->val = sum%10;
    printf("result->val: %d, sum: %d, carry: %d\n",result->val,sum,carry); 
    //result = result->next;

  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Input

```
[2,4,3]
[5,6,4]
```

Expect

```
[7,0,8]
```

Stdout

```
result->val: 7, sum: 7, carry: 0
result->val: 0, sum: 10, carry: 1
result->val: 8, sum: 8, carry: 0
```

Actully out:

```
[8]
```

---

I think maybe loss

```
result = result->next;
```

in while loop,

so I add it after `printf()`.

But Output seems null

```
[]
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger to step thru the code and examine it as it runs. If you still need help here then please provide minimal complete code that can reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: We don't have access to leetcode tests. You need to show the code that constructs the linked lists that are passed to the function.

Comment: `result = (struct ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode) );` You are overwriting the head node every time. Use two variables - one for the head node (to be returned) and one for the last node (for adding next node).

Comment: Since `result->next` is made `NULL` at each iteration, running `result = result->next;` just makes `result` equal to `NULL`.

Comment: Basically you lost the head of your linked list :(

Comment: @cigien, that code isn't necessary to understand this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're re-assigning the value of `result` during each iteration.  Therefore, no matter how many iterations there are, you'll only have a length-one linked list.  Furthermore, you'll have leaked a bunch of memory.

Instead, you should do something like

```
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2){
  struct ListNode *result = NULL; // Initialize the variable.
  struct ListNode *last = NULL;
  bool carry = false; // There is no need for this to be volatile.
  while ((l1 != NULL) || (l2 != NULL) ) {
    struct ListNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode)); // You shouldn't cast the result of malloc.
    if ( !temp ) {
        // handle the error somehow
    }
    temp->next = NULL;
    int v1 = 0;     
    if (l1 != NULL) {
      v1 = l1->val;
      l1 = l1->next;
    }
    
    int v2 = 0;     
    if (l2 != NULL) {
      v2 = l2->val;
      l2 = l2->next;
    }
        
    int sum = v1 + v2;
    if (carry)
      sum++;
    carry = (sum > 9);
        
    temp->val = sum%10;
    printf("result->val: %d, sum: %d, carry: %d\n",temp->val,sum,carry); 

    if ( last ) {
      last->next = temp;
    }
    else {
      result = temp;
    }
    last = temp;
  }
  
  return result;
}
```